# pyqtgraph cutting off axis numbers at top and right

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to get padding at the top and right side of a pyqtgraph plot, so that the numbers at the edge of the axes aren't cut off, which is the default behavior when creating a graph.

[image]

There was a similar question asked here, but the solution at the bottom does not seem very good; having to constantly update/re-draw the plot zoomed out: [How do I prevent pyqtgraph from making the axis larger than the widget size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119049/how-do-i-prevent-pyqtgraph-from-making-the-axis-larger-than-the-widget-size)

Example code to reproduce the issue:

mainwindow.py:

```py
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')

        loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)

        self.xAxis = []
        self.yAxis = []

        self.pgPlotSetup()
        self.updateGraphPlot()
        self.show()

    def pgPlotSetup(self):
        self.p1 = self.graphicsView.plotItem
        self.p1.setClipToView(True)

        # x axis
        self.p1.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', units='s', color='r', **{'font-size':'10pt'})

        # Y1 axis
        self.p1.setLabel('left', 'Voltage', units='V', color='b', **{'font-size':'10pt'})
        self.pen_Y = pg.mkPen(color='k', width=1)

    def updateGraphPlot(self):
        X = np.asarray(self.xAxis, dtype=np.float32)
        Y = np.asarray(self.yAxis, dtype=np.float32)

        self.p1.clear()
        self.p1.plot(X,Y,pen=self.pen_Y, name="V")

        app.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwindow.ui:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>287</width>
    <height>275</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <widget class="PlotWidget" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>287</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```